# Are all finite groups isomorphic to multiplicative group of a ring

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, finite-groups

Are all finite groups isomorphic to the multiplicative group of a ring. If I know the multiplicative group, can I define the addition as a function of 2 variables for all groups?

Comment: A ring doesn't have a multiplicative group. It does have a multiplicative group of units.

Comment: There's ambiguity on whether you want $G$ to embed as a subgroup of $R^\times$, or to be isomorphic to $R^\times$.

Comment: I wanted it to be isomorphic to multiplicative group of units.